# how to go to three.js page using pure website - Expected a JavaScript module

Tags: html, css, three.js, vite

I need to create a pure html, css and php website that has a button that when click it'll redirect you to the three.js page.

I tried using `<script type="module" src="src/main.jsx"></script>` and this :

```
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to the PHP Website</h1>
    <button onclick="redirectToThreeJS()">Go</button>

    <script>
        function redirectToThreeJS() {
            window.location.href = "three/index.html";
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

but when I click it doesn't run the three.js program (we usually can run it with vite package) it just shows a blank page with the title that I wrote in `<title>` of the three/index.html
and also this error in console :

main.jsx:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Comment: "_pure html, css and php website_" Requirements not met, you're using JS. Why not use a plain and simple `<a>` element to link to that page? (You might want to post your `three/index.html` page if that's the one that isn't working)

Comment: How is that Javascript related to "_how to go to three.js page using php_"? That's not using PHP

Comment: removed the PHP tag as it you are asking support for a HTML page where JS redirect is not working.

Comment: @brombeer actually now I have a error in console : `main.jsx:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`