# Compile and show three.js page using php

Tags: php, html, css, reactjs, three.js

I need to compile and show this tutorial(https://github.com/wass08/table-configurator-three-js-r3F-tutorial-final) result with pure php.
It's a react three.js page that allows user to edit a 3d table and I can run and see it using `vite` but I need to run it with a button on my pure php/css website

Actually I have an existing website that I want to redirect to the three.js page (jsx) using a button.

I tried some ways like script type. Changing mime type and etc. But still nothing.

Comment: I'm unsure what this has to do with PHP.  It sounds like you're looking for a simple link `<a href="your-url-here">my link</a>`

Comment: @RobEyre I created my website using php and I need to send and recieve some data with php to three.js . It doesn't work with `<a href>`. It shows a white page

Comment: As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77387286/how-to-go-to-three-js-page-using-pure-website-expected-a-javascript-module#comment136428188_77387286 (your other account?) the problem seems to be the three.js page, not linking to it. I don't see how a `<a href`> would _not_ link to that page. That the page itself doesn't work seems to be the problem here. Hard to help without seeing any of your code

Comment: @brombeer he's my co-workee. We can run three.js page with vite and I don't know what link should I write in `<a href>` for this situation. You mean run the three.js page with `vite' and then put the address of vite in a `<a>` tag?

Comment: Are you having trouble linking to a page? Or getting the threejs-page to work at all? Both your questions sound like you cannot _link_ to a page. Maybe ask the repository's maintainer for any help?

Comment: @brombeer imagine you want the users to choose what they want to configure and then redirect to the react three.js page with table/chair or anything they chose and save for example.

Comment: @brombeer I don't have problem with running three.js itself (using vite). I need it to run when I click on a button in my main website for example. I want the three.js page to be my sub domain